# dist(as.matrix) of HUGE table

Tags: r

I'm just starting with R and ran into a problem.

I want to `hclust` a table with a lot of data.

The data consists of a matrix with:

```
> nrow(hell)
[1] 202397
> ncol(hell)
[1] 39840
```

The matrix consists of integers (mostly 0 but of course higher values too).

Now I managed to read my 15gb txtfile on a 48core, 280gb RAM linux machine with `read.table()` but if I want to compute the distance matrix, it fails with this error:

```
d <- dist(as.matrix(hell))
Error in unlist(x,recursive, use.names):
resulting vector exceeds vector length limit in 'AnswerType'
```

I already googled around but couldn't find an answer (or understand how to deal with this).
Any chances to do what I want? :(

Comment: My datafile looks like this:
Abbild 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 ...
Abenteuer 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 ...

All the rows look like this and have the same number of columns.
Wouldn't this do it? 
I tried it with a _MUCH_ smaller file and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Likely the "column" you are referring to is not a column. They are _row names_.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that.

Comment: You want to hierarchically cluster 200K+ observations, and then what? Couldn't you do this with a small sample and then repeat that several times to see if the same sorts of clusters come out?

Comment: The main point is what Gavin said - it doesn't make any sense to do what you want to do, but to answer your question, use recent R on a 64-bit machine and you won't get the error (you'll get stuck at a later point instead ;)).

Comment: I can't reduce the observations, I need all of them because I'm clustering nouns(rows) with their corresponding frequency when seen with verbs(columns). What I will do is trying to reduce the columns. I guess that will help in size? Would it make sense to switch rows<==>columns so I get larger vectors but less observations?
Thanks for your answers!!

Answer (score 2):

```
> 202397^2 > .Machine$integer.max
[1] TRUE
```

R uses integers to index its vectors and matrices, matrices being a sort of folded vector. Some tasks will be too large for R. Even if you divide that product by 2 to account for the fact that a distance matrix only needs to hold the lower triangular part of the n^2/2-n calculations, it still requires a longer vector than R can construct.

```
> 202397^2/2- 202397 > .Machine$integer.max
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That is not true - at least not in R 3.0.0 and higher. R switches from integer to double indexing for large vectors and matrices. So, you can do the above
> d=dist(matrix(rnorm(1e5*5),,5))
> length(d)
[1] 4999950000
> .Machine$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
... you'll need at least 152GB of RAM just for the distance matrix and it doesn't make any sense, but that's another story ...

Comment: I have wondered exactly what changed (and I have 3.0.1). There was an announcement saying 8 byte indexing was coming, but my efforts to construct 8 byte integers have been failing. So 'integer.max' is the same 2^31-1, but the indexing is now capable of 8 byte width? How does that work in practice, if integers still max out at the old limit? There would seem to be a lot of documentation that needs to be changed, including the `?'['` page that says `[` coerces `i,j` arguments with `as.integer` however `as.integer(2^31)` returns `NA`

Comment: You may have missed the "R switches from integer to double indexing" part (double as the type), but yes, it's quite possible that some docs may need to be updated. Please consult the corresponding mailing lists.

Comment: I don't think I "missed it" so much as asked for clarification of contradictory information. So the new (theoretic) limit is 2^53?

Comment: yes. (AFAICS you were talking about integers hence the missing part)